# Trying to pass along x509 client certificate to second server

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, client-certificates

I'm trying to give server "A" the ability to connect to server "B" using the same X509 client certificate it received from the user.  Here are the basics of where I am so far:

```
public int makeRemoteCall() {
    URL url = new URL("https://host.com/service/request");
    HttpsURLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    SSLSocketFactory factory = getFactoryFromSessionCert();
    conn.setSSLSocketFactory(factory);
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    return responseCode;
}


public static SSLSocketFactory getFactoryFromSessionCert() throws Exception {
    HttpServletRequest request = getRequest();
    X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("client_cert", certs[0]);

    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore,  null);

    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

    return context.getSocketFactory();
}
```

I am able to retrieve the client's certificate without trouble, and can verify that it does indeed end up in `keyStore`. But the certificate doesn't seem to make it into `keyManagerFactory`.

I thought the issue was that I'm not providing a password in `keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore,  null)`, so I tried providing it but without success.  And should I even have to? I understand that I would need a password if I were loading certificates and keys from a protected file, but here I'm just trying to pass along an already exposed public certificate.

As further background, this basic scheme works if I replace `getFactoryFromSessionCert()` with this:

```
public static SSLSocketFactory getFactory(File pKeyFile, String pKeyPassword) throws Exception {

    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(pKeyFile);
    keyStore.load(keyInput, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());
    keyInput.close();

    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore,  pKeyPassword.toCharArray());
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
    return context.getSocketFactory();
}
```

So, what am I not understanding? And how *should* I pass along a client certificate?

Comment: There's a lot of concepts about PKI being misused in your code. You can't use a X509Certificate without a private key to start a SSL connection, the server in the other side will never accept the handshake. If you have plans to just pass the X509 along you can set it in the header of the new request. The simple answer is... you can't reuse the mutual TLS channel in the second server because you don't have the private key to make the key exchange.

Comment: Thanks, @argoth . I wasn't thinking of it like that, but it makes sense now. So, assuming I can make the second SSL connection with the server's own certificate, can the original client certificate be passed along to the second server in a way that satisfies client authentication?  I can make your suggestion of sending it in the header work (thanks!), but what would be the proper way of solving this?  I imagine it's a common need.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I realize what I'm really talking about is some kind of centralized authentication.  Like Kerberos, except that's overkill for my needs.  I'll probably go with putting at least the essential information in the headers or a cookie, but this seems like a really bad practice in general. What would be the simplest legitimate approach?